# How to make a QCompleter object run on a worker thread

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I wish to implement several autocompleters where the data passed to `QCompleter` is huge (63000 items), and therefore freezes the main thread. I read the `QCompleter` class docs but didn't find any reference to the question title, and `setMaxVisibleItems` isn't really what I look for, since the whole search is carried out anyway. Alternatively, limiting the search in some way to a fixed number of items as a workaround could be a valid option (also no reference to that in the docs). Maybe there is a simpler way I haven't noticed?

## Update

> main.py

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets as qtw
from itertools import chain
import csv
import traceback


class WorkerSignals(QtCore.QObject):
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    error = QtCore.pyqtSignal(tuple)
    result = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)
    progress = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)


class Worker(QtCore.QRunnable):
    def __init__(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        self.fn = fn
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.signals = WorkerSignals()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        try:
            result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        except:
            traceback.print_exc()
            exctype, value = sys.exc_info()[:2]
            self.signals.error.emit((exctype, value, traceback.format_exc()))
        else:
            self.signals.result.emit(result)
        finally:
            self.signals.finished.emit()


class MainWindow(qtw.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setLayout(qtw.QVBoxLayout())
        self.searchBox = qtw.QLineEdit()
        self.layout().addWidget(self.searchBox)
        path = r"components.csv"
        with open(path, "r") as f:
            self.data = list(chain.from_iterable(csv.reader(f)))
        self.data.sort()
        self.threadpool = QtCore.QThreadPool()
        # can't have completer on another thread
        # self.worker_fn(self.create_completer)
        self.create_completer()
        self.show()

    def worker_fn(self, fn):
        worker = Worker(fn)
        self.threadpool.start(worker)

    def create_completer(self):
        completer = qtw.QCompleter(self.data)
        # case sensitive by default
        completer.setModelSorting(qtw.QCompleter.CaseSensitivelySortedModel)
        self.searchBox.setCompleter(completer)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

> components.csv

[components.csv](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/danicc097/aa41e0c7a3b7113ffd637d6ce5640d65/raw/6aa331c4865d9914149db751c63bcc23720716c4/components.csv)

Comment: Aren't 63000 items a bit too much for a completion? And how is that model loaded?

Comment: It's meant to only show existent components in my database, so unique items are 63k minimum. I convert them to a list and just do `completer=QCompleter(list)`. The alternative is to setup my own completer showing an overlapped widget on the GUI below the `QLineEdit` every time the text changes, running on a `QRunnable`, but I was hoping to find something much more straightforward with the default class.

Comment: I don't know how you're loading the database, but I'm pretty sure that the whole process of loading > converting to list > adding to completer (which will create a new data model for it) is a big bottleneck. If the database is SQL based, you could start by using QSqlTableModel (or QSqlQueryModel) instead, which will surely improve performance. Using `setMaxVisibleItems` will give no benefit, as it's only used to resize the popup.

Comment: Presumably you're using a [sorted model](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcompleter.html#modelSorting-prop)?

Comment: I added a MRE to test. The data itself is a simple CSV file, though large. The `QCompleter` model just gets set once, but I suppose trying to fill that internal combobox when the `QLIneEdit` changes is very expensive (`setModelSorting` didn't improve performance here, for some reason).